# How to Collect info from IntentService and Update Android UI

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm learning Android and I'm stuck with my service.

My application connects via Socket to my server every X seconds, receives an XML, parses the information and it's shows in a TextView.

I'd like to know how can I implement an IntenService to do this and how to communicate the info to the UI. I'm finding very hard to see good examples.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a handler and send a message to parent activity from the intentservice

**Parent Activity** :

Declaring Handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle reply = msg.getData();
                            // do whatever with the bundle here
            }
};
```

Invoking the intentservice:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntentService1.class);
        intent.putExtra("messenger", new Messenger(handler));
        startService(intent);
```

Inside **IntentService**:

```
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Messenger messenger = (Messenger) bundle.get("messenger");
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.setData(bundle); //put the data here
        try {
            messenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.i("error", "error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to use an AlarmManager to start the Service every x seconds?

Comment: Thank you so much Farhan! I'll have a look.

Comment: congrats. you used the worst variable name for this example:

"msg.setData(data);"

data??? really? everything is data...

Comment: What if Intent service is not started from Activity but from Application (for refreshing data every X seconds) ?