# How do i get text from one activity and put it on a button in another activity.

Tags: android

I want to know how I can get the text from an edittext in Activity B and put that text on the button of Activity A. I want to make it so that when i press the "enter" button on activity b it will get the text of the edittext and replace the text of a button in activity A. I think its something like this

```
    public void pressEnter (View v){
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String t = et.getText().toString();
    Button p1_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    p1_button.setText(t);
}
```

but i dont know how to get the ID of the button from activity A that I want to set the text to.

Comment: I think you should send a broadcast message.

Comment: Don't try to directly change any part of the UI of one `Activity` from another `Activity`. If a `Button` in activity A needs its text changed then it is the responsibility of activity A to do it *NOT* activity B. You should pass the text from one `Activity` to the other or save the text using something like `SharedPreferences` so the other `Activity` can retrieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to start Activity B with `startActivityForResult()`.

Good example of usage can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/554002) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use messenger, it also works for off-UI threads when you want to talk to the UI thread:
[How to Collect info from IntentService and Update Android UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871521/how-to-collect-info-from-intentservice-and-update-android-ui)

Comment: Not really a good idea between `Activities`. It is also tricky between something like a `Service` and an `Activity` as you have no guarantee that the user hasn't left the `Activity` at which point it may have been destroyed

Answer (score 0):

if you make the variables static you can refer to them in eachother with the dot operator like:

```
ActivityA.p1_button or ActivityB.t
```