# Best way to update ui from an IntentService?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I am currently writing an app that needs to be able to play audio.
As i want the audio to continue playing when the user leaves the app, i am using an IntentService to handle the play method.

My problem is that i need to be able to update the applications UI, such as a progress bar showing how much is remaining of the audio, using data from the intentservice.

I was just wondering what the best way of achieving this would be?
I have googled this, but all the guides seem to be for AsyncTask or just standard services.

Thanks heaps to anyone who can help.

Cheers
Corey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `Handler` and `Messenger` class.

Someone already post a good answer here (its also use `Handler` and `Messenger`) :

[How to Collect info from IntentService and Update Android UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871521/how-to-collect-info-from-intentservice-and-update-android-ui)

Answer (score 0):

We can even use Local Broadcast for this purpose.Please refer below link.

[How to Collect info from IntentService and Update Android UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871521/how-to-collect-info-from-intentservice-and-update-android-ui/64496236#64496236)

Comment: Most of your post is the same link as in the existing, upvoted and accepted answer. Please consider making your additional contribution more obvious.