# Long running background task, Android

Tags: android, service

I am parsing all text messages from the device and extracting words from them. For doing this I first used `Service`, but the issue with it was that it made application slower or sometimes I got notification that Application is taking longer to run. 
Alternative to this I used `IntentService`. But problem with intent service is that whenever I stopped the application, I couldn't see my service running anymore. Alongside I also have to use Alarm Manager to schedule the things. 
I am planning to use `SyncAdapter` for doing both of the things, but I don't think it would be a good option to use it. It would be really helpful if there is a better possible for doing this.

Background task might take upto 5-10 minutes for completion and I am planning to run it in every 12 hours. Though I won't be parsing old messages again. So it won't take longer after first time. The task should not end even when application is closed.

Comment: Did you execute your parsing in `onStartCommand` of `Service`? If yes, than it's the reason of your system gave you ANR (App not responding).
Try the AsyncTasks, they are pretty designer for this.

Comment: I think the real problem is that he did the work in the service on the main thread

Comment: I get it. I am doing it in onStartCommand, Services run on UI Thread, so I have to use a Thread/AsyncTask to do things inside service, right?

Comment: @AngadSingh `Service` runs in the background but on the main thread (ui thread) but `IntentService` runs on a separate worker thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `IntentService` is apt for background tasks which are not tied to the application lifecycle.

> But problem with intent service is that whenever I stopped the
>   application, I couldn't see my service running anymore.

You can send updates to UI from intent service by using:

`LocalBroadcastManager`:   [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

`Handler`: [How to Collect info from IntentService and Update Android UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871521/how-to-collect-info-from-intentservice-and-update-android-ui)

Also you might want to see this video: [The Zen of IntentService. (Android Performance Patterns)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FweabuBi1U)

**EDIT**:
Forget about using `IntentService`, it stops as the app stops because it runs on the same process as the app.

Since you want your service to work as a job every 12 hours, you could use a 'Scheduled Service'.
You can use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#js) or  [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#fjd) API

Comment: The only UI element I want to change is the Notification in Notification bar, the service runs independently and makes only changes in the database. Binding it with application won't make a difference.

Comment: Actually it wont even make sense to update the app UI from a background service which is not bound to the app. Have you tried showing notification from an `IntentService`?

Comment: Yes, I am showing the progress notification in progress notification bar from IntentService, closing the app stops the progress updates. It works perfectly till the app is running/

Comment: @AngadSingh You can use `startForeground()` with an `IntentService` which will prevent it from stopping until finished.

Comment: It is working! but, the service is getting restarted on its own after completing...

Comment: @AngadSingh I don't know what might be causing it. But a JobScheduler could be a better option to use for your use case. Check the answer, I have edited it

Comment: Problem was with the alarm manager. It's working perfectly. Thanks!